# styled-components — how to use :not() selector on a prop?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Let's say I have an element with a property **"selected"**:

```
<Button selected>
    Text
</Button>
```

---

```
const Button = styled.div`
    &:not(???) {
        color: red;
    }
`;
```

How do I select all instances of *Button* which don't have the **"selected"** property?

Maybe there is another way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

---

**Сlarification edit:**

I actually need to use :not together with :hover, like this:

```
const Button = styled.div`
    &:not(???):hover {
        color: red;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you can do it:

```
const Button = styled.div`
    ${props => !props.selected && css`
        :hover {
            color: red;
        }`
    }
`;
```

Don't forget to import ***css*** from **styled-components**;

Answer (score 2):

styled-components uses some template magic to allow you to access passed props like so:

```js
const Button = styled.div`
    color: ${props => props.selected ? "color when selected" : "red"};
`;
```

With styled-components, this tends to be the more idiomatic way of setting things based on props rather than using CSS selectors.

Comment: The thing is, I actually need this :not to be used together with :hover. I probably should have reflected this in my question.